# How can I change a class variable after initialization in groovy?

Tags: grails

I have the following:

```
class Img {
  static constraints = {
    imageSize(nullable: true, maxSize: 1000)
  }
}
```

and I would like to change the maxSize of the imageSize variable to something else in my program, I tried this but it didn't work:

```
def img = new Img()
images.imageSize.maxSize = 800
```

Edit:

```
class Img {
  byte[] imageSize

  static constraints = {
    imageSize(nullable: false, maxSize: 1000)
  }
}
```

Comment: Is `Img` a domain class in a grails app or any other `validateable` groovy class?

Comment: Yes it is a domain class.

Comment: Can you show the full domain class including the properties at least the `imageSize` property?

Comment: I've updated the question with more information.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
ConstrainedProperty constrainedProperty = Img.constraints.imageSize
constrainedProperty.setMaxSize(800)
```

Comment: Nope I don't think it recognizes the .imageSize part. Thanks for your help though, any other ideas?

Comment: It does for me, why not for you?

Comment: I get the following error: No such property: bytes for class: proj.Img
Possible solutions: bytes, type

Comment: I guess you have defined Long imageSize in your domain, correct?

Comment: Its defined as byte[] imageSize

Comment: @Grammin It is complaining about `bytes`. This approach should work. Can you try testing the same approach for something other than `byte[]`, for example, try with `String`.

Comment: I tried it for string, no luck.  Is this the right import for ConstrainedProperty: import org.codehaus.groovy.grails.validation.ConstrainedProperty